# How to push to an array in useState with multiple field in array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const[data, setDate] = useState({
  field1 : [{
     f1: "",
     f2: "",
  }],
  field2: [{
     f3: "",
     f4: "",
  }]
})
```

In the above how I can update and push new element to field1 and field2

Comment: `let newArr = data; newArr.push(yourData);
setDate(newArr)`

Comment: By "element" do you mean "key/value" pair. Adding `f3: ""` to `field1` for example?

Comment: Actually the problem is if i want to push fields from a form that the user will give input individually for each field then how to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [data, setDate] = useState({
    field1: [
      {
        f1: "",
        f2: ""
      }
    ],
    field2: [
      {
        f3: "",
        f4: ""
      }
    ]
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = { ...data };
    temp.field1.push({ f3: "" });
    setDate(temp);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question what if I take input from a form, and each has fields like f6, f7 and want to push same element of array let say field4

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
let temp={...data};
temp.field1.push(...);
temp.field2.push(...);

setDate(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question what if I take input from a form, and each has fields like f6, f7 and want to push same element of array let say field4